# If statement Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, webforms, null

I know this is probably rather trivial but I have had a look at previous questions and I've tried them but they still issued an error unfortunately :s

My issue is the following, I have an html.erb file and I want a certain body text to be display given a condition or another if it is false

I have

`<% if !@selector.nil do %>`

more code goes here

`<% end %>`

I have tried many combinations but the most frequent error i keep getting is

`You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.nil`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, this is most likely something very easy but I can't find my way through it!

Comment: Jim's answer below is the correct one (the method is called "nil?", not "nil"), but I just wanted to point out that the "do" in your code isn't necessary, and is going to cause you problems if you leave it in ("do" in Ruby starts a block, but in this case the "if" has already started the block so "do" is unnecessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `.nil` method.  You're thinking of `.nil?`. It should be `!@selector.nil?`.

Or you could get the same result from `if @selector` and it will evaluate to be the same as `if !@selector.nil?`.  This is assuming you not referring to a boolean.

Comment: You're right on the first count, but not the second. Usually "if @selector" will be as good as "if !@selector.nil?" but to speak precisely they aren't equivalent--for example, if @selector is supposed to be boolean and the poster wants false and nil to give different results

Comment: Jordan, you're right.  I assumed he was referring to a record.

Comment: cheers! the .nil? worked great, i had it in some previous code version but i must have removed it when i tried some count or so! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I updated it so nobody will get confused in the future.  Thanks Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try .nil? or == nil, or take a close look at your controller code that's assigning a value to @selector.

Answer (score 0):

just

```
if @selector
```

is enough

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, a more idiomatic way would be <% if @selector.present? do %> or in idiomatic Ruby <% unless @selector.nil? do %>